# Barra de progresso não é atualizada corretamente

Tags: java, swing

Trabalhando com barra de progresso (`JProgressBar`) me deparei um problema em `PropertyChangeListener`. Aliás, não necessariamente em `PropertyChangeListener`, mas sim no momento de retornar a propriedade que está sendo atualizada.

```java
Tarefa tarefa = new Tarefa();
tarefa.addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener() {
     @Override
     public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
          if("progress".equals(evt.getPropertyName())){
               int progresso = (Integer) evt.getNewValue();
               barra.setValue(progresso);
          }
     }
});
tarefa.execute();
```

Como dá para notar, é necessário que a propriedade a ser atualizada seja "progress", porém não é isso que ocorre. Pelo menos não inicialmente. A propriedade que é retornada é "state", com isso a condição não é aceita, e o valor da barra de progresso não é atualizado.

O que pode estar errado?

---

Eis a class `Tarefa`:

```java
public class Tarefa extends SwingWorker<Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
        int progresso = 0;
        setProgress(0);
        while(progresso < 100){
             progresso++;
             setProgress(progresso);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Como exatamente é a classe Tarefa? O que ela faz?

Comment: Você está usando Swing?

Comment: A classe Tarefe é uma extensão de que classe? E como ele feita você fez extensão?

Comment: Utilize o debugger e coloque um Breakpoint na linha `if("progress".equals(evt.getPropertyName())){` e verifique o nome de todas as propriedades, algum deles será o que você deseja, provavelmente você irá deduzir qual é pelo nome.

Comment: A classe Tarefa estende de SwingWorker: public class Tarefa extends SwingWorker<Void, Void>{
E ela só contém basicamente o método doInBackground, cujo código é o seguinte: @Override
 protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
  int progresso = 0;
  setProgress(0);
  
  while(progresso < 100){
   progresso++;
   setProgress(progresso);
  }
  return null;
 }

Comment: Usando um breakpoint, a propriedade que é retornada é "state".

Comment: Se você colocar um `Thread.sleep(100);` antes do `setProgress` e deixar ele rodar por 10 segundos, o que acontece?

Comment: Por que precisa dessa linha `if("progress".equals(evt.getPropertyName())){`?

Comment: `Thread.sleep` antes de chamar `setProgress` faz com que ele atrase o tempo especificado, e logo após complete a tarefa de uma vez.
Porém `Thread.sleep` como último comando dentro do _while_ faz tudo funcionar perfeitamente!

Comment: `if("progress".equals(evt.getPropertyName())){` serve para descobrir se é a propriedade progress que está sendo atualizada e com isso atualizar também o valor da barra de propriedades.

Answer (score 2):

Quando for executar a tarefa, executa com `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(tarefa);`.

Lembrando que: toda estrutura do Swing não é *thread-safe*.

Comment: Não conheço Swing. Esta resposta responde ao que o autor perguntou?

Answer (score 1):

Acontece que o código está chamando o `setProgress` muito rápido e quando o evento é disparado o  progresso já está em 100%

Se colocar um `Thread.sleep( 20 );` dentro do `while` vai ver que o evento vai ser disparado mais vezes.

OBS: Se o código rodar rápido de mais não faz sentido ter uma JProgressBar para monitorar o andamento da tarefa.

Comment: Entendi! E inseri o `Threade.sleep` dentro o while e funcionou perfeitamente.
E o código está bem simples porque eu ainda estou tentando aprender como tudo funciona para posteriormente inseri-lo em minha aplicação.